# Calculating $\int \sin x e^x \Bbb d x$ by parts twice

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

Integrate $e^x \sin x  $. I know I need to integrate by parts 2 times, but I'm stuck at the second integration. For the first I get

$$-e^x \cos x  - \int e^x\cdot (-\cos x)  \,dx  $$

Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Can you show us what you did, and *where* you are stuck in the second integration?

Comment: Clement is right.  Show us what you tried.  The rest of you: wait until he does.

Answer (score 2):

Use IBP again:

$u = e^x, dv = \cos x$

You should come up with an $\int e^x \sin(x) dx$ after that. Rearrange the equation to solve for $\int e^x \sin(x) dx$. It's [loopy](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=L8HoALsls-E)

Answer (score 2):

Start with: $\int e^{x}\sin(x)dx=e^{x}(A\sin(x)+B\cos(x))$

Answer (score 0):

You started with $u=e^x, dv=\sin x dx$.  The usual mistake is to take $u=\cos x, dv=e^xdx$ the second time.  That leads to a circle and your integral cancels out.  You need to take $u=e^x, v=\cos x dx$ the second time.  Now things don't cancel, you get twice the original integral.